# Python: sorting an array with another array's elements as keys?

Tags: python, sorting

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(10 * 30)).reshape(100, 3)
y = np.array(range(1010, 10, -10))
res = sorted(x, key = lambda y:y) #ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
res = sorted(x, key=y) #TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is your question/problem, and what are you trying to do?  It would be nice to have some more description instead of just posting code.

Comment: sort the x array using the values in the y array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try argsort:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(10 * 30)).reshape(100, 3)
y = np.array(range(1010, 10, -10))
args = y.argsort(axis = 0)
print x[args]
```

Comment: This is cool -- but perhaps this should be `args = y.argsort()` and `print x[args]`? At least that seems to be what the OP is asking for...

Comment: Yeah you have to change the two last lines like senderle said but that's what I wanted thanks.